# Why do I get scrapy response empty?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I started

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0' https://www.gumtree.com/p/property-to-rent/brand-new-modern-studio-flat-%C2%A31056pcm-all-bills-included-in-willesden-green-area/1303463798
```

Next step

```
In [5]: response                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[5]: <405 https://www.gumtree.com/p/property-to-rent/brand-new-modern-studio-flat-%C2%A31056pcm-all-bills-included-in-willesden-green-area/1303463798>
```

After inspected page element,and copied XPath

```
In [6]: response.xpath('//*[@id="ad-title"]').extract()                                                                                                                                                     
Out[6]: []
```

Copy outerHTML

```
<h1 itemprop="name" id="ad-title">Brand New Modern Studio Flat £1056pcm | All Bills Included | In Willesden Green area</h1>
```

Image view response
[image]

Why?

Comment: If you look closely, the response says `405`. This is an error code.

Comment: How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the user agent to something more realistic, such as: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0`.

Some websites do some basic validation on the user agent and redirect you to some special page if they detect something weird.

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0' https://www.gumtree.com/p/property-to-rent/brand-new-modern-studio-flat-%C2%A31056pcm-all-bills-included-in-willesden-green-area/1303463798
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="ad-title"]').extract()
['<h1 itemprop="name" id="ad-title">Brand New Modern Studio Flat £1056pcm | All Bills Included | In Willesden Green area</h1>']
>>>
```